# Spring MVC dropdown box

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I have been trying to find out how to create a dropdown box in Spring MVC. 
Here is my controller:

```
@ResourceMapping(value = "availableDataVis")
public String getAvailableDataVis(Model model,
                            @RequestParam("widgetId") String widgetId) {
    HashMap<String,Map<String,String>> hashMapOfDataVis = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();

    Map<String,String> m = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    m.put("pie", "Pie Chart");
    m.put("categorizedVertical", "Column Chart");
    hashMapOfDataVis.put("m", m);

    if (hashMapOfDataVis.containsKey(widgetId))
    {
        model.addAttribute("dataVisArray", hashMapOfDataVis.get(widgetId));
    }

    return "selDataVisComboBox";
}
```

and here is the jsp page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<form:select path="dataVisArray" items="${dataVisArray}" />
```

Actual output:

```
ERROR
Cause: javax.portlet.PortletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'dataVisArray' available as request attribute
Message: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'dataVisArray' available as request attribute
StackTrace:
javax.portlet.PortletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'dataVisArray' available as request attribute
    at org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.jsr168.api.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:169)
    at org.jboss.portal.portlet.impl.jsr168.api.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:84)
...
```

Expected output:

```
<select id="dataVis" name="dataVis">
   <option value="pie">Pie Chart</option>
   <option value="categorizedVertical">Column Chart</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This code will only work if the widgetId request parameter = "m". Have you checked that's true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried doing something like this?

```
<form:select path="dataVisArray"><br />
     <form:option label="Select..." value=""/>
     <form:options items="${dataVisArray} itemLabel="label" itemValue="value"/>
</form:select>
```