# Spring MVC Drop down box throws error

Tags: spring-mvc, drop-down-menu, jsp-tags

I followed the steps in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482993/spring-mvc-dropdown-box) and I am still running into problems.

My Controller looks as follows...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "listBooks.htm")
public String goToNextPage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request){

    HashMap<String,Map<String,String>> hashMapOfData = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();

    Map<String,String> m = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    m.put("1", "foo");
    m.put("2", "bar");
    hashMapOfData.put("m", m);
    model.addAttribute("dropdownData", hashMapOfData);
.....
}
```

My jsp file...

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<form:select path="dropdownData"><br />
 <form:option label="Select..." value=""/>
 <form:options items="${dropdownData}" itemLabel="label" itemValue="value"/>
</form:select>
```

I get the error...

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'value' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'value' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter

BUT if I change my jsp file to...  removing the `itemLabel="label" itemValue="value"`

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<form:select path="dropdownData"><br />
 <form:option label="Select..." value=""/>
 <form:options items="${dropdownData}"/>
</form:select>
```

The page does load, but the drop down box selections are

- Select...
- {1=foo, 2=bar}

Can anyone help me out? I am quite a novice when it comes to Spring MVC so very detailed answered would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error describes it all

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'value' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'value' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter
```

Spring is trying to find a getter for value within the java.lang.String, something that doesn't exist.

I'd just use a `List<LabelValueModel>` (LabelValueModel being something you make yourself, which has the properties for label and value.

Your final jsp would look like this then:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<form:select path="dropdownData"><br />
 <form:option label="Select..." value=""/>
 <form:options items="${dropdownData}" itemLabel="label" itemValue="value"/>
</form:select>
```

LabelValueModel would just be a simple POJO to avoid binding to a specific technology:

```
public class LabelValueModel
{
  private String label;
  private String value;

  ..public getters..
  ..might consider private setters and only allowing setting through constructor..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you go into how I would make a LabelValueModel a little more?

Comment: Uhg I'm still confused. I created the LabelValueModel Class. Where would List<LabelValueModel> go in my controller?

Comment: As a replacement to your double Map, in the backend, that jsp tag is being parsed, the items attribute of the form:options tag is calling keySet() on the Map, which returns an iteration of java.lang.String.  This is object is then being passed to the itemLabel and itemValue attributes, which looks for getters within java.lang.String with the value of getLabel and getValue due to itemLabel being label, and itemValue value.  If you pass in a list of the POJO, the getters will be there, and the Strings will be shown.

Comment: HashMap<String,List<LabelValueModel>> hashMapOfData = new HashMap<String,List<LabelValueModel>>(); ??

Sorry, If someone could simply edit my Controller with the minor changes, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, just List<LabelValueModel> no reason to have a map for this, in fact, it's just making things more complex.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22785/discussion-between-zack-and-dardo)